# Angular login function in login component

Tags: angular, authentication

```
loginNew(logindata:any){
   this.service.loginUser(this.user).subscribe(()=>{
        console.warn(logindata);
        this.alertify.success("Successfully entered!");
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000);});
  }
```

This is my function but I don't know how to write if the entrance is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to return a success function in case of success, or a failure function in case of failure.,

In that case, You will be able to control the user output for whatever outcomes.

```js
loginNew(logindata:any){
   this.service.loginUser(this.user).subscribe(
        (success) => {
        console.warn(logindata);
        this.alertify.success("Successfully entered!");
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000);});
  },
       (failure) => {
          alert(failure.message)
       }
  }
```